# constant reverting of R.java with ADT r14

Tags: android, adt

since ADT r14 I get a lot of errors like this:

```
[2011-10-21 17:51:22 - library] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

but I am not changing the R.java at all. Anyone knows whats going on there? is that a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you killing the Android emulator during the build?  Do you see any *.out.xml files?

Do a clean by right clicking on the project ->Clean, then manually delete all the *.out.xml files, then try building.

**Ninja edit**  Looks like there might be a bug in ADT 14:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21031

Answer (score 1):

did you try cleaning the project ?

Comment: yes - I do that by reflex when problems in the ADT occour I do not expect ;-)